# SQL Query for get a join between two tables with a multiple condional SUM() in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

It is possible in MS ACCESS 2016 to join a table that is a multi-conditional SUM of another table?

Example:

Table 1 - Columns

ID, NAME, TOTAL

Table 2 - Columns

ID, NAME, IDREF, ROOTID, CUSTO

Data:

Table 1

```
ID | Name  | Total
---+-------+------
35 |  Test |  "SUM(CUSTO) of ALL ELEMENTS OF TABLE 2 WHERE table2.IDREF = table1.ID **or** table2.ROOTID = table1.ID"
```

Table 2

```
ID | Name  | IDREF | CUSTO | ROOTID   |
---+-------+-------+-------+----------+
1  | Test  |  35   |   50  |   0      |
2  | Test  |  35   |   30  |   0      |
3  | ALFA  |  12   |   30  |   0      |
4  | BETA  |  17   |   10  |   35     |
```

The result should be:

table 1

```
ID | Name | Total
---+------+------
35 | Test |  90  (50 + 30 from table 2 where idref = 35 and + 10 from table 2 where rootid = 35)
```

it is very similar as one of my previous question, but i think a multi condional sum is very hard to do in ms-access need some help.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a couple of sub-queries to get the total for each, and add them together:

```
SELECT T1.ID, 
NZ((SELECT SUM(T2.Custo) FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T1.ID=T2.IDRef),0) +
NZ((SELECT SUM(T2A.Custo) FROM Table2 AS T2A WHERE T1.ID=T2A.RootID) ,0) AS Total
FROM Table1 AS T1;
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks! it works! and it is very fast. I have some questions: what the NZ() function does? it Creates a variable or a subquery in access? it works in other databases?

Comment: It is an Access function, "Null to Zero", used to ensure that if there is nothing returned by a sub-query, we get a 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join with multiple ON conditions as below,

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID,
    t1.Name,
    SUM(t2.CUSTID) AS Total
FROM 
    t2 
    INNER JOIN 
    t1 
ON 
    t2.IDREF = t1.ID
    OR
    t2.ROOTID =t1.ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID,
    t1.NAME
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    Total
35  Test    90
```

Comment: It works, the return is what i would expect. but in terms of speed, my "real" table has 11000 row aprox. so this solution takes 10 - 20 seconds for a return. Anyway thank you very much!